# Comparing values from different tables using triggers

Tags: sql, postgresql, database-trigger

so the problem is I have two tables and before inserting or updating the values on one table I have to check if the other table does not contain the new value I'm trying to insert/update like so:

```
CREATE TABLE categoriasimples(
    nome varchar(64) PRIMARY KEY REFERENCES categoria(nome) ON DELETE CASCADE);

CREATE TABLE supercategoria(
    nome varchar(64) PRIMARY KEY REFERENCES categoria(nome) ON DELETE CASCADE);

CREATE FUNCTION check_categoria_type_sup() RETURNS trigger AS $check_categoria_type_sup$
    BEGIN
        IF nome FROM categoriasimples WHERE (NEW.nome = CategoriaSimples.nome) IS NOT NULL THEN
            RAISE EXCEPTION 'Uma categoria nao pode ser super e simples ao mesmo tempo!';
        END IF;

        RETURN NEW;
    END;
$check_categoria_type_sup$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER check_categoria_type_sup BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON supercategoria FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE check_categoria_type_sup();

CREATE FUNCTION check_categoria_type_simp() RETURNS trigger AS $check_categoria_type_simp$
    BEGIN
        IF nome FROM supercategoria WHERE (supercategoria.nome = NEW.nome) IS NOT NULL THEN
            RAISE EXCEPTION 'Uma categoria nao pode ser simples e super ao mesmo tempo!';
        END IF;

        RETURN NEW;
    END;
$check_categoria_type_simp$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER check_categoria_type_simp BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON categoriasimples FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE check_categoria_type_simp();
```

I can insert values into one table but if I try to insert in the other table it says:

**ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type boolean: "bife" (Value that was in the other table)
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function check_categoria_type_sup() line 3 at IF
SQL state: 22P02**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is too long for a comment.

I'm pretty sure you can do what you want without using triggers.  I would suggest that you investigate *[inheritance](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/tutorial-inheritance.html)*, which Postgres supports for tables.

You can just define a unique constraint on the parent table and not have to worry about trying to get two different tables to be in sync.

Comment: upvoted: for suggesting to avois triggers. Also OP can use `IF` in the same statemente or just put a `WHERE`

Comment: So basicly I can't use triggers to do this or I simple have to aviod them ? Beacuse I was reading what @Gordon Linoff said for me to read and Inheritance does not support Unique constraints or Foreign Keys which are two things I have in my tables. All I wanted to do was check other tables for the value I'm trying to insert into another table

Comment: @Pmsmm . . . I'm not a fan of triggers, unless necessary.  This answer suggests an alternative that is not trigger-based.

Comment: I thank you all a lot for the help, I'll try not to use triggers then